# Errors about too few arguments

Tags: c, compiler-errors

The below returns too few arguments in the `int main` section on the `fp` and `newton` lines.
Can you explain this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
double f(double a, double b, double c, double x)
{
   return pow(x,3)+a*pow(x,2)+b*x+c;
}

double fp(double a, double b, double c, double x)
{
   return 3*pow(x,2)+(2*a*x)+b+0*c;
}

double newton(double a, double b, double c, double x)
{
   return x - (f(a,b,c,x)/fp(a,b,c,x));
}

int main()
{
   double a,b,c,x1,x2; 
   int i;
   char *input = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
   sscanf(input, "coeff1=%lf &coeff2=%lf &coeff3=%lf &x=%lf", &a, &b, &c, &x1);
   if (fp(x1)==0.0)
   {
      printf("No convergence.\n");
      return 0;
   }
   for (i=0;i<100;i++)
   {
      x2=newton(x1);
      if (fabs(x1-x2)<= pow(10,-10)) break;
      x1=x2;
   }
   printf("iteration = %d\n", i);
   printf("x= %lf\n", x1);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DavidPilkington Sure looks like C to me.

Comment: I feel it is C...I am in a Numerical Analysis/Programming class and we are entering these commands in unix (basic system commands)

Comment: @user3016224 You should probably at least know for sure what language you're programming in. These aren't *system commands*, it is C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just what the error says! You haven't passed enough arguments:

This prototype:

```
fp(double a, double b, double c, double x) {
```

means you need to pass four arguments, like:

```
fp(x1, what, about, these);
```

The same goes for `newton`.

Also, regarding `if (fp(x1)==0.0)` - While floating point zero values *can* be compared with each other (zero is *excatly* zero), remember that floating-point on computers is *not exact*.  For that reason, you should always compare against some epsilon value:

```
#define EPSILON           0.0001     // salt to taste
#define ABS(x)            ( ((x)<0) ? -(x) : x )
#define FP_EQUALS(x,y)    (ABS(x-y) < EPSILON)

//if (d == 0.0) {
if (FP_EQUALS(d, 0.0)) {
    // d is "zero"
}

//if (a == b) {
if (FP_EQUALS(a, b) {
```

Comment: Thank you so very much!  My partner figured that out at the same time (we've been staring at it for over an hour).  Would that epsilon value be a complex formula or just some computed number close to 0?

Comment: @user3016224 Some value close to zero. It is related to the maximum error your program should allow in calculations.